# Creating a SOAP client with wss security

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, webservice-client, ws-security

I need to create a service client that accesses a secure service.

I have created a service stubs from wsdl file with cxf over maven, and now I am trying to sign the SOAP header, but I cannot make any header appear on the soap request.

I have tried to find any example on google, but the few found did not provide any header in the request.

I have also tried to include cxf-rt-ws-security but i am not able to pull all the dependencies from that because it says Failure to find net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0

Any help with that would greatly be appreciated.

As for the header I'm trying to get in the soap request, it should look like this:

```
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
        <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EncKeyId-679555506">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                            <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Service</ds:X509IssuerName>
                            <ds:X509SerialNumber>1208931986</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                        </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>*****</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:ReferenceList>
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#EncDataId-160481262" />
            </xenc:ReferenceList>
        </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="CertId--168360">*****</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-1901480989">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-160481262">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <ds:DigestValue>*****=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>*****
            </ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-274944844">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STRId--395421404">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#CertId--168360" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
    <wsa:To>http://www.example.com/ExampleService?wsdl</wsa:To>
    <wsa:MessageID>*****</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:Action>http://www.example.com/ExampleService/check</wsa:Action>
</soapenv:Header>
```